# How the triggered event cause the program jump to the hook point?

Tags: linux, ebpf

I'm new to eBPF, and I know that eBPF is event-driven, which means after we register the hook point, the hook function will be executed when such an event happens. So I wonder how the program can jump to the hook function?

Answer (score 2):

There's an explicit call to the BPF program from the kernel code. For example, we can check [the XDP hook in the Amazon ENA driver](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18.1/source/drivers/net/ethernet/amazon/ena/ena_netdev.c#L377):

```
xdp_prog = READ_ONCE(rx_ring->xdp_bpf_prog);

if (!xdp_prog)
    goto out;

verdict = bpf_prog_run_xdp(xdp_prog, xdp);
```

It first checks if a BPF program is loaded; i.e., `rx_ring->xdp_bpf_prog` is not NULL. And it then runs that BPF program with the `struct xdf_buff` object as argument (named `xdp` here). The rest of the code handles the return code (`verdict`) from the BPF program.

You can find the same sort of logic for all BPF program types.

Comment: Wow!! really awesome!

Answer (score 1):

pchaigno's answer is good.

As a complement, there are some other eBPF program types for which you don't have pre-defined hooks and calls. For example, you do not have an explicit call for *every* function in the kernel where you could attach a kprobe. In such case, some different mechanisms may be at play:

> When a kprobe is registered, Kprobes makes a copy of the probed instruction and replaces the first byte(s) of the probed instruction with a breakpoint instruction (e.g., int3 on i386 and x86_64).

This breakpoint is used to redirect the CPU to the probe - [more details here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.18/trace/kprobes.html#how-does-a-kprobe-work). This is what happens as well in the case of BPF programs attached to kprobes.

Comment: Well, that's true for kprobes themselves, but there is still an explicit call to BPF from the k(ret)?probes handlers, same as with the networking hooks: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18.2/source/kernel/trace/bpf_trace.c#L100.

Answer (score 0):

Great answers :)
As a complement about retprobes: Like said before, they also work by replacing instructions with int3 (on x86); it is nice to watch with gdb.
However, they do this at the beginning of the function; the called trampoline replaces the return address. You can easily see this in a small test program, which prints the stack with and without the retprobe being active.
You'll notice that the stack cannot be read correctly (at least by `backtrace(...)`).

Usually, retprobes work well. However, keep in mind that they tamper with the stack (in an unexpected way). At least with g++, they break exception handling when the probed callee raises an exception that is handled in the caller.